# ui-router not changing the state using $state.go() in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have successfully get data from rest call. code is working fine.but when I am trying to get the data from its id. but data is printing in to the console but it is not changing the state. I am unable to do this. 
here is my code:
service.js:

```
this.getRecordDetail=function(comp_id){
                console.log('inside Record');
                return $http.get(baseUrl + '/' + comp_id)
                    .success(function(response){
                        deferred.resolve(response.data);
                        return deferred.promise;
                    },function(error){
                        deferred.reject(error);
                        return deferred.promise;
                    });
            }
    }
```

controller.js:

```
  $scope.getRecord =function(comp_id){
                console.log('inside record controller');
                detailService.getRecordDetail(comp_id).then(function(data){
                    $scope.cur_record=data.data;
                    console.log($scope.cur_record);
                    $state.go('record.details', {'userId':comp_id});
                });
            },
              $scope.getRecordName=function(){
               console.log('inside getRecordName');
               $scope.getRecord(userId);

            }
```

in template :
   view

Comment: Make sure `record.details` router is available? And give me this code.

Comment: yes it is available. everything is working fine.but it doesnt chane the state

Comment: is there any error messages?

Comment: You need to add your routing config into this post otherwise it is very hard to help

Comment: I have not mention <div ui-view></div> it is working now.but the problem is when i refresh ithe page it is showing me the content